# What is 'summary execution'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, jargon

While reading this [blog](https://www.rt.com/news/331832-un-report-syria-torture/), I could not find the meaning of 'summary execution'.

When I tried to find the meaning of this phrase, I got the phrases like '[summary judgement](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summary%20judgment)', and '[summary proceeding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summary%20proceeding)'.

My questions are: What is a meaning of 'summary execution'? Is it a legal jargon or an idiomatic phrase as it is written with an inverted comma?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a search for [summary execution define](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=summary+execution+define&gws_rd=ssl) shows this is an easily answerable "basic question on meaning."

Comment: @GoDucks: [Very few dictionaries list it](http://onelook.com/?w=summary+execution&ls=a), and both are online-only; our policy on dictionary reference questions is intended to allow someone who normally looks up words in one or two good, recently published, hard-copy dictionaries they possess to ask questions about anything not found in those.

Comment: Military speak for "murder"

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future - search first just for the word you don't understand, not the entire phrase. If you looked up [summary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/summary) you would see when it is used as an adjective it has a definition like "(of legal proceedings, jurisdiction, etc.) conducted without, or exempt from, the various steps and delays of a formal trial".

Comment: Also [***summary***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/summary) #2

Comment: @NathanTuggy so much for "your policy". Many of us didn't get the memo.

Comment: @GoDucks: Well, now you have, I guess. This has been discussed on meta a number of times; it's a fairly subtle point, but it *is* a fairly common policy. Look for e.g. J.R.'s posts about this.

Comment: @GoDucks: [For example](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1102/10820).

Comment: I've not seen any policy but yours which stipulates *"one or two good, recently published, hard-copy dictionaries they possess"*. What if a user has only one, or not even one, of those kind and of dictionaries? It's okay for such a user to ask for definitions easily findable by a definition search? @NathanTuggy

Comment: @GoDucks: J.R.'s answer that I linked, with a score of 16, is such a policy, although it does not specify "one or two"; that's a rough paraphrase of the general principle. (If anything, my phrasing is more restrictive.) And **yes** it is OK if a user asks a question that can be found elsewhere online; you can *downvote*, if you like, but *closing* is wholly inappropriate on this and any other Stack for "insufficient effort". (*That*, in particular, has been enormously belabored on Meta SO over the years. The consensus is strong, but there's a vocal minority.)

Comment: Any learner that can readily separate and identify 'summary execution' can even more readily and easily type in "summary execution define" to any major browser and get multiple definitions and sample uses.

Answer (score 9):

The word [**summary**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/summary) in your example is not a noun, but an **adjective** which means:

> Law (Of a judicial process) conducted without the customary legal
>   formalities.

*Summary execution* means:

> an execution in which a person is accused of a crime and **immediately
>   killed** without benefit of a full and fair trial.

You could find more about [**summary execution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_execution) in the Wikipedia article.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]